# In a matrix-/vector-equation $\small A*x=B*y$ must $\small \operatorname{sign}(\det(A))=\operatorname{sign}(\det(B))$?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I've a matrix-equation and I'm trying to list the conditions under which that equation can be true. The equation is of the form:
$$\small \begin{pmatrix} -A & B+b \\ A+a & -B \end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} m_1  \\ m_2 \end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix} -c & D \\ C & -d \end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} r_1  \\ r_2 \end{pmatrix}
$$
All numbers are expected to be integer and positive, the small letters have smaller (a and b) or smaller-or-equal (c and d) absolute values than the resp. capital letters. Also *A* to *D* , *a* to *d,r1,r2* are given (or more exactly, functions of two problem-parameters) and I'm studying the restrictions that lay on *m1* and *m2*. Because from the configuration of the problem I can assume, the determinant of the most-left matrix is negative, and I wonder, whether this means, that the determinant of the 2x2-matrix on the rhs must also be negative. This must be an extremely simple question but I don't just find the key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The determinants of the matrix on the right is 
$cd - CD$, so if $0 < c \le C$ and $0 < d \le D$, certainly $cd - CD \le 0$, with equality only if $c=C$ and $d=D$.  Now with $c=C$ and $d=D$, the right side of your equation is
$$\pmatrix{- c r_1 + d r_2\cr c r_1 - d r_2\cr}$$
so adding the two entries we must have $0 = a m_1 + b m_2$, which can't happen if everything is positive.

Comment: ahh, thanks! I just thought, there would be some general rule when determinants and a right-multiplication are involved, and I should perhaps just know it... In more general cases, the determinants can even have opposite sign? Hmm...